# 1 yellow, 1 red & 1 yellow card

Tags: rules, football, suspension

If a player receives a yellow card in a game, then a red card in another game (serves a 1 match suspension) then receives another yellow card in a later match. Does he have serve a suspension for the next match because of 2 yellow cards?

Comment: Yes, yellow card count won't be reset by a red card suspension normally

Comment: Please specify which competition you're talking about; rules will be different.

Answer (score 8):

As suggested in the comments it depends on what tournaments are you writtend about.

i.e.

***Italian Serie A*** the player will be disqualifie after the **5th** yellow cards (since last tournaments it was at the 4th). The second disqualification will be at the **10th** yellow cards, then at the **14th**, then at the **17th**, then at the **19th**, then every yellow card collected in that tournament (see the [art 19 comma 9](http://www.figc.it/Assets/contentresources_2/ContenutoGenerico/32.$plit/C_2_ContenutoGenerico_2529084_StrilloComunicatoUfficiale_lstAllegati_0_upfAllegato.pdf) and the [box in the image below in italian language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnXM4.png))

[image: box in the image below]

**UEFA** competitions used to disqualified the players after **3** yellow cards in 3 different matches, than after the **5th**, the **7h** (see [art 49](http://www.uefa.org/MultimediaFiles/Download/Regulations/uefaorg/Regulations/02/23/57/51/2235751_DOWNLOAD.pdf) and the image below) and so on until the semi-final. After the quarter-finals (art 49.04) the yellow cards are reset to do not affect the topics of the tournaments (i.e. [Nedved misses EURO Champions League 2003](http://www.uefa.com/uefachampionsleague/season=2002/matches/round=1639/match=1044119/postmatch/report/index.html) and Xabi Alonso misses EURO Champions League final in 2014) [image: image below]

Answer (score 7):

2 yellow cards in different games don't account for suspension, they **need to be in the same game.**

However, consider this example:

In the EPL, a **straight red card for a professional foul means a one match ban.**

Also, **5 separate yellow cards** accrued before new year also means a one match ban(extended to 10 yellows till April, after new year)

So if a player is on 4 yellows, and then gets a straight red, he will be banned for a game. (1 game for a professional foul, 3 games for violent conduct)

If he comes back, and immediately gets another yellow, he is banned again for a game.